# Ember - Deserialize not being called by router for dynamic route containing id

Tags: ember.js

I have constructed the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/rgHyB/130/) that illustrates my problem.

In the above gist, I have a route that contains a dynamic id segment:

```
cowan: Ember.Route.extend
  route: '/:cowan_id'
    connectOutlets: (router, cowan) ->
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('cowan', cowan)
    serialize: (router, id) ->
      {cowan_id: id}                    
    deserialize: (router, params) ->
      console.log 'never gets here, do I need to put this logic in connectOutlets?'
      App.cowans.filter((cow) -> cow.get('id') == params.cowan_id).get('firstObject')
```

The problem is that deserialize does not get called when I entering this route.

I think when _id is in the url that connectOutlets is called instead.

Am I wrong or why is deserialize not being called?

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle has some bugs, but I am going to assume that was just because you only wanted to provide enough code to show the `deserialize`. I'm ignoring those bugs for now.

The deserialize function only gets called when you enter a route through the URL. It basically materializes (deserializes) a URL into a Ember objects. Transitioning to the route from another state will not deserialize, because by that point there should be nothing to deserialize.

You can see that when you use this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/rgHyB/134/show/#/cowans/1 that your router is actually deserializing. Whatever `deserialize` returns will be the 2nd parameter to `connectOutlets`. Also, `deserialize` can return a promise, allowing you to enter connectOutlets at a later time. This allows you to wait for an ajax call to complete.

Comment: Makes sense, I am passing the context via the action helper.  There is absolutely no need for deserialization.  I could just pass the object :).

Comment: I am curious to know what the bugs are.

Comment: @dagda1 here is I think the complete working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/rgHyB/144/. Since few weeks, ids are coerced to string, so you need either to manage this in the deserialize (1 != "1") either declare your ids as strings. In the action helper, pass the complete object, not just the id. Finally, in the serialize method, get the id instead of the complete object.